# How to separate by lines a 2d array grid in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to to create a basic mutiplication table printed out as a grid 2d integer array, basicly I'm having trouble to sepatate the numbers with lines for example "----" or |-|, anyway, below is the basic 2d integer array already showing a multiplication table. Please help to separate each number with lines to get view as an excell table or smtg like that.

package Multip;

public class Multitest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

int[][] multiplicationTable = new int[10][10];

```
    for (int row=0; row<10; row++) {
      for (int col=0; col<10; col++) {
          
    multiplicationTable[row][col] = (row+1) * (col+1);
  }
}

    for (int row = 0; row < multiplicationTable.length; row++) {    
        
for (row = 0; row < multiplicationTable.length; row++) {

    for (int col = 0; col < multiplicationTable[row].length; col++) {       
        
       System.out.printf("%4d", multiplicationTable[row][col]);
  }       
    System.out.println();
}
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can print a new line with underscore in another for loop after your initial loop which prints the numbers. Then your inner loop might look something like this. The count of underscore would be the space you're giving in between each digit

```
for (int col = 0; col < multiplicationTable[row].length; col++) {

    System.out.printf(" %4d |", multiplicationTable[row][col]);
}
System.out.println();
for (int col = 0; col < multiplicationTable[row].length; col++) {

    System.out.print("_______");
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Thank You Singh3y it works fine:-), if I can get another question I'd ask for Your help with following: This code will work by scanned in numbers provided by user for example firstNumber and secondNumber (to multiply them of course), this method is ready, but my task is to print out only rows which equals with both of provided numbers and columns which equals with also both of provided numbers. so how to print out only two columns and 2 rows and get rest of table empty?

Comment: @Jacek517 can you give a short example. I'm not getting your question.

Comment: OK, so there are scanned in two numbers for example 4 and 5, the existing table showing all numbers, the fields are filled as a normal multiplication table, but when I get 2 numbers 4 and 5 from user I would like to print out only that kind of table which shows only row 4 and row 5 and column 4 and column 5.

Comment: You can just add a continue statement for other number. Then they would be skipped.

Comment: ````if(row != input1 && row != input2) {
                    continue;
                }```` You can add this condition after your second for loop